# passing an array from codeigniter controller to file in /assets

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created an array with my controller. Let's call it $result. I need to access $result in MyReport.php which is located in /assets. The array is small in my sample but really could be thousands of lines. How can I pass the array so it can be accessed by the code running in MyReport.php? I have thought of using $_SESSION[$result] but I am concerned about the size. Is there a size limitation in $_SESSION? Any other way using CI to pass and large array from my controller to code running in /assets/MyReport.php?

Comment: What's myreport.php? A view, helper, lib, custom script and whats it doing? Can't you inclide it in the controller or view or model?

Comment: any reasons why MyReport.php is located in /assets ? also read about [Creating Ancillary Classes](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/ancillary_classes.html#creating-ancillary-classes). Using that concept you could write a helper, which creates that $result array and you are set.

Comment: MyReport is a php file located in /assets. Why there? that is where the makers of kooklreport decided it should go. It comes we two required functions setup() and settings(). Settings opens the connection to databases. Setup creates the datasources. Here is an example of one.